# MongoDB $pull no elimina el dato del array

Tags: mongodb

Tengo el siguiente objeto JSON y quiero eliminar un elemento del array de numero del subObjeto Telefono, pero no funciona.
ejemplo del objeto:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f9b1ed088ab8f2cdcce0168"
    },
    "cedula": 1040500,
    "nombre": "Diego",
    "apellido": "Corredor",
    "genero": "M",
    "edad": 29,
    "Telefono": {
        "numero": [3184005481, 3181007845],
        "operador": ["movistar", "movistar"],
        "saldo": [20000, 25000]
    },
    "Correo": {
        "email": ["diegoc@gmail.com", "corredordie@hotmail.com", "diegoc@yahoo.es"],
        "servidor": ["gmail", "hotmail", "yahoo"],
        "contrasena": ["corredordx", "diegoc7", "corredordx"]
    }
}
```

Y quiero hacer la siguiente operación utilizando $pull:

```
db.Persona.update({"nombre":"Diego"},{$pull:{numero:3184005481}},{multi:true})
```

Y sale el siguiente resultado pero no se elimina el dato

```
{ acknowledged: 1,
  insertedId: null,
  matchedCount: 1,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedCount: 0 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea usar el operador [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/index.html) para eliminar un elemento de un campo de tipo `Array` de un documento de MongoDB, usando la siguiente consulta:

```
db.Persona.update({ "nombre": "Diego" },{ $pull: {numero: 3184005481 }}, { multi: true })
```

Sin embargo al aplicar el método sobre el campo, el mismo no es eliminado, obteniéndose el siguiente resultado:

```js
{ 
  acknowledged: 1,
  insertedId: null,
  matchedCount: 1,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedCount: 0
}
```

Que indica que la operación no se realizó: `modifiedCount: 0`, aunque si se consiguió el documento: `matchedCount: 1`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es simple, estás olvidando que el campo `numero` es un campo de un subdocumento (o documento anidado) perteneciente al campo `Telefono`.

Según la documentación, el operador `$pull` se aplica sobre campos de tipo `Array`, y cuando el campo está en un subdocumento, entonces para referirse al mismo debes usar [notación de punto](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation).

Por lo cual tu consulta debe ser reescrita como:

```js
db.Persona.update({ "nombre": "Diego" },{ $pull: { "Telefono.numero": 3184005481 }}, { multi: true })
```

Puedes notar que me refiero al campo `numero` como `"Telefono.numero"`, ya que sería esta la forma de indicarle a MongoDB que acceda a los campos de documentos anidados.